# Hacks to reduce page limit for ieee

Tags: bibliographies, itemize, ieeetran

I want to shrink the length of my paper `\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}`to fit within page limits so I tried the 
`\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
{\footnotesize \bibliography{Bib}}`

and `\addtolength{\itemsep}{-0.05in}`

But none of them worked 
Thank you

Comment: Are you publishing with the IEEE? I don't think they will look favourably upon those kind of tricks to get around their page limit. These tricks will probably not survive the publishing process anyway.

Comment: I have many references and there is extra space made by \itemize.

Comment: I just had a look at the space in `itemize` in `IEEEtran` and to me it actually looked quite reasonable. Certainly not as large (some might say excessive) as in the standard classes. With `\addtolength{\itemsep}{-0.05in}` the items were too close. As for the bibliography: IEEE bibliographies are already typeset in a slightly smaller size, if you make that even smaller it will become unreadable.

Comment: I tried the \vspace and it helped for the \itemize issue